# How do I highlight a camelCase word in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I am trying to highlight a camelCase word in WebStorm, For example, firstName.
However, It's doesn't highlight the entire word, highlight a portion of it, first or Name.
How can I select or highlight the entire word?
I am using WebStorm 2022.3 version.

[image]

Comment: In general, you just double click on the word or symbol (variable/class name/function name etc) and it should select the whole thing. If it does not then please check you `CamelHump` your settings at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys`. With my settings (see https://i.imgur.com/mqqagLk.png ) it will select the whole thing; if I have both highlighted option enabled then it will select just 1 word from the camelCased word.

Comment: In either case, 1) place caret at start (or end) of the word and then use `Ctrl+Shift+Right` (or `Left`) to extend or shrink the selection by words. 2) You can also use `Edit | Extend Selection` to extend your selection to the next level(s). In your case, if you have just `Name` part selected then invoking this action will select the whole `firstName`.

Comment: If that's not what you meant / what you are after then please describe your situation (what you do right now to make that selection) and what you want to have in more details.